# textarea asp-for doesn't display property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been working on a small school project and decided to use .net core (MVC) for the first time. I have a small button I can click which executes the "ipconfig" command in the background and displays the output in a text area. At first my team partner used only a

```
public string Result;
```

in ViewModel for the view. In the view it's displayed via

```
<textarea asp-for="Result"></textarea>
```

So I decided to make it into a property with default get and set:

```
public string Result { get; set; }
```

But when I do that, the output doesn't show up in the textarea if I keep the same approach in the view as my team member did when he used a field instead of a property. Instead I have to do it like this to get it to show up in the textarea:

```
<textarea>@Model.Result</textarea>
```

Now I'm asking myself why this happens. Can't I display Properties with asp-for? And what would be better to use, a field or a property as Result?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly, the name of your property is clashing with something else. Like explained here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5525

Comment: I tried to rename the property into "CommandResult" but it didn't help

Answer (score 7):

In my case this behavior was happening because I did not have a separate closing tag on my textarea. I know your example above has it when using the `asp-for` method, but in case that was a copy/paste error, you may want to look at that again.

```
<textarea asp-for="Message" type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" id="MessageInputField" autofocus></textarea>
```

As opposed to:

```
<textarea asp-for="Message" type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" id="MessageInputField" autofocus />
```

This is incredibly annoying 'gotcha' like behavior in my opinion.  And maybe if someone wants to tell me why it isn't, then please enlighten me, I'm always willing to learn.

Comment: Because textarea isn't supposed to be a self closing tag. And because razor tag helpers specify if they should run for self closing tags or not. (eg https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L17 vs https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/TextAreaTagHelper.cs#L15)

Answer (score 2):

You should actually be using properties, and if `<textarea>@Model.Result</textarea>` works, `<textarea asp-for="Result"></textarea>` should as well. The only reason it wouldn't is if the `ModelState` has a different value for `Result` (as the latter form actually uses `ModelState`, whereas the former is obviously using `Model` directly).

`ModelState` is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag`, and finally `Model`, so for example, if you were to do something like `ViewBag.Result = String.Empty`, that would actually override the value from `Model` in `ModelState`.

There's no enough code here to truly diagnose the exact issue, but I would look for other places you might be using "result" (case-insensitive). If you're accepting that as a request param or setting a `ViewBag` member, etc. that's your problem.

Comment: I never put another value in Viewbag or ViewData under "Result". I also changed the property name already once which didn't help solving my issue. It's not like it's interrupting the functionality of my application atm but I really wanted to understand why that wasn't working

Comment: That _"…only reason it wouldn't…'_ was the kicker for me. The model has a property `Message`, which I can easily imagine finding in Request!

Answer (score 0):

I find this is a bit weird in .Net Core 6, when I want two-way binding - ie displaying the result

With asp-for I have to self close the tag AND add the additional textarea close tag to get the result displayed.

```
    <textarea asp-for="Result" />@Model.Result</textarea>
```

This works but is not syntactically correct.
Without the self-close tag, the result was not being display

```
    <textarea asp-for="Result">@Model.Result</textarea>    @*Does not display the value*@
```

For display only, this is more correct

```
    <textarea>@Model.Result</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late of an answer but hopefully will help someone in the future. So I learned that `asp-for` will overwrite the content of `textarea` that you might be trying to display as default [read here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14428#issuecomment-535596108). As an alternative, I found that a simple `Html.TextArea` tag helper will do the trick. You will get all the model validation behavior you get with `asp-for` along with your default content in `textarea`.

Use this:

```
@Html.TextArea("MyPropNameInModel", "my default content for textarea", new { @class = "form-control" });
```

Instead of:

```
<textarea asp-for="MyPropNameInModel" class="form-control">my default content for textarea</textarea>
```