# <textarea> doesn't show inner text when together with "asp-for="

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, html-helper

This shows "Hello there" inside the textarea:

```
@model PlannerViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Test</h2>
<form method="post">
    <div class="border rounded">
        <textarea class="form-control MyTextArea" rows="4">Hello there</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

This doesn't show "Hello there" inside the text area:

```
@model PlannerViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Test</h2>
<form method="post">
    <div class="border rounded">
        <textarea class="form-control MyTextArea" rows="4" asp-for="EditShutdown.Comments_Operations">Hello there</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you see, the only difference is the presence of "asp-for". Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this annoying event, you can use ;

> @Html.IdFor

and

> @Html.NameFor

Example;

```
<textarea id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.EditShutdown.Comments_Operations)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.EditShutdown.Comments_Operations)">Hello there</textarea>
```

Comment: This is actually the only answer that solves the problem on .NET Core 3.1. Note that model validations wont work without `asp-for`, so here's hoping that this gets solved on .NET Core 5.0

Comment: I have an answer similar to this one that worked for me without losing model validation. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717292/textarea-asp-for-doesnt-display-property/76700966#76700966)

Answer (score 0):

`asp-for` gives `<textarea>` a `name` and fills its value, so you can just set `EditShutdown.Comments_Operations` value to `"Hello there"` in order to display it.

Comment: Hi #Alexander; it does't work. Even when EditShutdown.Ccomments_Operations already has a value on it, the <textarea> is blank.

Answer (score 0):

According to your request , you could try using `placeholder` attribute like below:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="border rounded">
    <textarea class="form-control MyTextArea" rows="4" placeholder="Hello there" asp-for="EditShutdown.Comments_Operations"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

When you do "Create" operation, you could see the prompt message `"Hello there"` ;and  when you do "Edit" operation, you could see the value of `EditShutdown.Comments_Operations`.

For `asp-for` attribute , you could refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Xueli Chen: "Placeholder"'s intent is to create watermarks, not to fill boxes with texts. In this case I gave it a try and the text "Hello there" appears but disappears immediately after clicking on it, as it's supposed to - the user is therefore not able to edit that text.

Comment: What operation is the text box used for ，Add or Update? What effect do you want to achieve?